# Auto complete WooCommerce orders depending on total amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I wish to disable auto-complete orders but only for those orders where amount is higher than 30 EUR for example. All products are virtual.

I found this function on net:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'stop_auto_complete_order' );
function stop_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'processing' );
}
```

However I have no clue how to make it only if order is higher than specific amount.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some [`WC_Order` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) like:

- The total order amount: `get_total()`
- The order status: `get_status()`

Based on your code, the following will:

- auto-complete paid orders up to 30 (will be set to "completed" status)
- auto-process paid orders bigger than 30 (will be set to "processing" status)

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'stop_auto_complete_order' );
function stop_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Auto-complete paid orders up to 30 (for "on-hold" and "processing" order statuses)
    if ( $order->get_total() <= 30 && in_array( $order->get_status(), [ 'on-hold', 'processing' ] ) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    } 
    // Other paid orders are set to "processing" status
    elseif( $order->get_status() === 'on-hold' ) {
        $order->update_status( 'processing' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I've tried it but it does not work. Tested both in child theme and then directly in main theme...

Comment: What are payment gateways IDs that you are using and what status they have on a successful (paid) order (without making change to them with some code)? … Your question details are poor.

Comment: Using only PayPal without any additions to code.
There's no option to make status after paid order.

Comment: is it possible that it's not working because paypal is capturing payments?